# Android RenderScript doesn't show Textures

Tags: android, renderscript

I have a problem with RenderScript. Textures I bind will be not shown on the Surface. I don't get any errors or relevant notes in LogCat or in Console. I use an WallPaperService.Engine. I Bind Bitmaps in ProgramFragments let it show in rsgBindProgramFragment. I have this problem with several tutorials too. The Bitmap, ProgramFragments etc a never null. When I prevent the binding of the Bitmap to the RenderScript, points instead of textures will be displayed. I have tried out several methods to decode Bitmaps, not compressed Bitmaps in a very small resolution too. I think it makes no sense to post the whole code here. Please ask for snippets. I work about a week on this problem. I am very grateful every sugestion to solve the problem. I test the solution on a Galaxy S3.

Comment: I have checkt my projects on Galaxy S2, Android 4.0.2 and it works. My device, Galaxy S3 Android 4.1.1 still doesn't show any textures.